# Get keys and values from dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a datastructure like this:

```
d={0:[{'key':'apple', 'count':50},{'key':'ibm', 'count':25}], 
1: [{'key':'apple', 'count':40},{'key':'ibm', 'count':29}],
2:[{'key':'apple', 'count':44},{'key':'ibm', 'count':21}]}
```

What I want to accomplish is get a list of the values for each of the tuples in the list.
What I am trying to do is:

```
zipped={}
count=0
for item in d:
    #print(item)
    for i in d[item]:
        zipped[count]=i['count']
        count+=1
```

The result I get is:

```
{0: 50, 1: 25, 2: 40, 3: 29, 4: 44, 5: 21}
```

What I want is something like:

```
{0:[50,25], 1:[40,29], 2:[44,21]}
```

How can I get that

Comment: `{k: [mp['count'] for mp in v] for k, v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you go too deep. I think you can get away with multiple list comprehension. It should work even if you have an undetermined number of internal values:

```
zipped = {key: [elem['count'] for elem in internal_list] for key, internal_list in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

res = { key:[value["count"] for value in values] for key,values in d.items()}

use this for your required result